# Finding the domain of $s$ and $t$ such that $225 - t$, $175 - t + s$, $200 - s$, and $-25 + t$ are all non-negative

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

I have these equations and given that $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$, $x_4$, t, s must all be equal or greater than $0$:

1. $x_1 = 225 - t$
2. $x_2 = 175 - t + s$
3. $x_3 = 200 - s$
4. $x_4 = -25 + t$

I'm having trouble determining a domain for $t$ and $s$.

I know $t\geq25$, and $s\leq200$, but I am having trouble with determining what $t$ has to be smaller (or equal than) and what $s$ has to be larger (or equal than).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have an inequality region. When you draw four lines on the coordinate plane, you will have a quadrilateral, and this is where all four constraints are satisfied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comment,  graphing the four inequalities then look at the overlap.  I converted $s$ to $x$ and $t$ to $y$ for this on geogebra.

[image: inequality]

As you can see, you need to be between $25\leq t\leq 225$,   then your $s$ bound is going to depend on $t$, as you need to be to the right of the diagonal line and to the left of the vertical,  so $t-175\leq s\leq 200$

Edit:

Comment added the requirement that $s\geq 0$, this changes our shape so we cut off the left triangle there.  Now we have vertical parallel lines, so  we get $0\leq s\leq 200$,  the vertical bounds get a bit trickier because you can go up to either the line or 225, whichever is smaller,  so $25\leq t\leq \min\{175+s,225\}$

Comment: Thanks! I seemed to have forgotten to clarify that s and t have to be greater or equal to zero as well. How would this affect the domain of s given that if t = 25 then s would be negative which is not allowed?

Comment: @Hayley I edited the solution,  you cut off at $x=0$ in that picture, so your $s$ bound is now simple, the $t$ one gets a little funky due to not being able to go over either the diagonal line or the horizontal one,  thus the minimum function

Comment: Thanks again! I have not learnt this graphing method of determining domains before. I was wondering if there was a way to do this algebraically?

Comment: For two dimensional domains like this based on inequalities?   Possibly,  but its so much easier to visualize it by just drawing the boundary curves and noting on what side of the curve you need to be on.  BTW, welcome to MSE, if this answered your question go ahead and mark the accept answer so it shows as completed (Plus awards a touch of reputation)

Comment: Is it then possible to write the domain of t as 25 ≤ t ≤ 175 + s ≤ 225?

Comment: No, that's not a well formed inequality alas,  as it would mas $s$ to 50  as well, which you don't want.  You pretty much need to use the min function